# Java How to access a protected method in a parent class in a different package

Tags: java, eclipse

There is an existing class with this method

protected HttpResponse post (String route, String json,BasicNameValuePair...parameters) throws IOException

I am creating a child class in a different package, but want to call this method. How do I do that?

Also, the parent class of the child class is abstract, so I can't instantiate it.

Comment: did you try, in your child class, to do something like that? -> super.post(params)...


protected means only child can access, doesn't matter the package location. If it was default, then it would matter.

Comment: @Lucas actualy, unlike C++, in java protected means that it can be accessed in the same package. (And in subclasses of course).

Comment: Default means it can only be accessed from the same package.
Protected means it can only be accessed from the child.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call protected method from a subclass of another instance of different packages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404260/call-protected-method-from-a-subclass-of-another-instance-of-different-packages)

Answer (score 1):

```
package package2;
import package1.Parent;
class Child extends Parent //assuming Parent is in package 1
{
   @Override
   protected HttpResponse post(...)
   {
       super.post(...)
       //Remaining stuff
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A commenter linked the answer here. I think I deleted that comment by mistake:

[Call protected method from a subclass of another instance of different packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404260/call-protected-method-from-a-subclass-of-another-instance-of-different-packages/14405008#14405008)

Answer (score -1):

William, you can call the method from any method of your child class provided the reference you use to invoke it is of the type of the child class or a subclass of it (the rationale, among other things, is explained in my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34768085/why-protected-access-modifier-works-differently-when-its-used-along-with-static/35018625#35018625) question). As a simplified example, consider this Parent class

```
package parent;

public class Parent {

    protected void method() {
        System.out.println("parent.Parent.method() called");
    }
}
```

extended by a Child class

```
package child;

import grandchild.Grandchild;
import parent.Parent;

public class Child extends Parent {

    public void anyMethod(Child child, Grandchild grandchild) {
        this.method();
        child.method();
        grandchild.method();
    }
}
```

extended, in turn, by a Grandchild class.

```
package grandchild;

import child.Child;

public class Grandchild extends Child {
}
```

Given this class hierarchy, this code

```
Child child1 = new Child();
Child child2 = new Child();
Grandchild grandchild = new Grandchild();
child1.anyMethod(child2, grandchild);
```

would produce the following output.

```
parent.Parent.method() called
parent.Parent.method() called
parent.Parent.method() called
```

So, a Child object can access its own protected method() member as well as the method() member of another instance of Child or of an instance of a subclass of Child. It can't, however, call the method using a reference whose type is Parent (unless it uses super) or a different subclass of Parent (say, Brother).

I hope this answers your question and gives you an idea of what you can (or can't) do. If not, let me know.